# How can I find the same elements in a column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a txt file .there is a dataset with 4 columns . First column's mean is telephone numbers . I have to find same telephone numbers. My txt file like this

```
...
0544147,23,86,40.761650,29.940929
0544147,23,104,40.768749,29.968599
0538333,21,184,40.764679,29.929543
05477900,21,204,40.773071,29.975010
0561554,23,47,40.764694,29.927397
0556645,24,6,40.821587,29.920273
...
```

and my code is

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
rdd_data = sc.textFile("dataset.txt")

data1 = []

lines = rdd_data.collect()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

for line in lines:
    data1.append([float(x.strip()) for x in line.split(',')])

column0 = [row[0] for row in data1] #first column is founded as a list
```

So I don't know how can I get same telephone numbers in first column. I'm too new about pyspark and python. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
rdd_data = sc.textFile("dataset.txt")

rdd_telephone_numbers = rdd_data.map(lambda line:line.split(",")).map(lambda line: int(line[0]))
print (rdd_telephone_numbers.collect()) # [544147, 544147, 538333, 5477900, 561554, 556645]
```

If you want an explanation of the step by step data transformations:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
rdd_data = sc.textFile("dataset.txt")

rdd_data_1 = rdd_data.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
# this will transform every row of your dataset
# you had these data in your dataset:
# 0544147,23,86,40.761650,29.940929
# 0544147,23,104,40.768749,29.968599
# ...........
# now you have a single RDD like this: 
# [[u'0544147', u'23', u'86', u'40.761650', u'29.940929'], [u'0544147', u'23', u'104', u'40.768749', u'29.968599'],....]

rdd_telephone_numbers = rdd_data_1.map(lambda line: int(line[0]))
# this will take only the first element of every line of the rdd, so now you have:
# [544147, 544147, 538333, 5477900, 561554, 556645]
```

Comment: Thank you so much , that is the exactly what I want :))

Comment: Also , I want to use these coloumn for eaxh row . I mean if I want 5th tel number , I need to see 5th number on the list. I mean Can I make the column a list ?    when I use rdd_telephone_numbers[5] , I want to see 5th number . I hope I could explain :)

Comment: RDDs do not support indexing, so you can't retrieve an element with  rdd_telephone_numbers[5]. You can do: list_telephone_numbers =rdd_telephone_numbers.collect() and then take the 5th element as list_telephone_numbers[5].  But remember that collect() should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s memory. [See here the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html)